# Replace a variable in a vector of strings with its quoted value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write this for loop:

```
    for (j in c("mxPH", "mnO2", "Cl", "NO3", "NH4", "oPO4", "PO4", "Chla", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", \
"a7"))
{
    for (i in c("summer", "autumn", "winter", "spring"))
        {
            maximum <- max(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, j], na.rm=T)
            message("The maximum of ", j, " for ", i," is: ", maximum)

            median <- median(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, j], na.rm=T)
            message("The median of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", median)

            mean <- mean(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, j], na.rm=T)
            message("The mean of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", mean)
        }
}
```

I thought the problem is with the variable j being replaced by its value without the quotation marks needed in any of the (maximum, median and mean) lines, which I tried to solve with this version:

```
    for (j in c("mxPH", "mnO2", "Cl", "NO3", "NH4", "oPO4", "PO4", "Chla", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", \
"a7"))
{
    for (i in c("summer", "autumn", "winter", "spring"))
        {
            mito <- paste("",j,"", sep="")
            maximum <- max(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, mito], na.rm=T)
            message("The maximum of ", j, " for ", i," is: ", maximum)

            median <- median(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, mito], na.rm=T)
            message("The median of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", median)

            mean <- mean(algae[algae$j>0 & algae$season == i,][, mito], na.rm=T)
            message("The mean of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", mean)
        }
}
```

Which did not work. How may I write this for loop properly?

Thank you all in advance

Edit:
[Here](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/DataSets/Analysis.txt) is the file I used for data:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified things a bit:

```
molecule<-c("mxPH", "mnO2", "Cl", "NO3", "NH4", "oPO4", "PO4", "Chla", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6","a7")
season<-c("summer", "autumn", "winter", "spring")

for (j in 1:length(molecule))
 {
  for (i in 1:length(season))
    {

        seasoni<-season[i]
        moleculej<-molecule[j]
        dat<-as.numeric(unlist(subset(algae,algae[,moleculej]>0 & algae$season == seasoni,select=moleculej)))
        maximum <- max(dat, na.rm=T)
        print(paste0("The maximum of ", moleculej, " for ", seasoni," is: ", maximum))

        med <- median(dat, na.rm=T)
        print(paste0("The median of ", moleculej, " for ",seasoni," is: ", med))

        meane <- mean(dat, na.rm=T)
        print(paste0("The mean of ", moleculej, " for ",seasoni," is: ", meane))
    }
  }
```

Segment of output:

```
[1] "The maximum of mxPH for summer is: 8.15"
[1] "The median of mxPH for summer is: 7.585"
[1] "The mean of mxPH for summer is: 7.6675"
[1] "The maximum of mxPH for autumn is: 8.1"
[1] "The median of mxPH for autumn is: 8.055"
[1] "The mean of mxPH for autumn is: 7.94"
[1] "The maximum of mxPH for winter is: 8.7"
[1] "The median of mxPH for winter is: 7.93"
[1] "The mean of mxPH for winter is: 8.04285714285714"
[1] "The maximum of mxPH for spring is: 8.35"
[1] "The median of mxPH for spring is: 7.79"
[1] "The mean of mxPH for spring is: 7.904"
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you.
Your script is far more elegant than mine, for sure.
Well, since I am still a beginner, was there anything that I could do to fix my version of the script. I am just asking to see if I could solve the problem with what I already know.
Thank you again.

Comment: @FaizLotfy, I would say you would fix your script by making it look like my script, but I may be a little biased, since I wrote it. Are there things in my script you do not understand? It mainly looked like you lack a general understanding of the R language (which is totally fine). I would just keep practicing and get some intro books on R to learn how the language works.

Comment: Of course your version is more elegant and useful than mine. I was trying to collect some statements together with a for loop.
I am just trying to see if I could solve the issue with what I already know.
I don't understand these items: as.numeric, unlist and subset?
I am reading about these commands now to see what I will learn from them.

Comment: The first thing to know was that you can't do `for(j in "LIST OF CHARS")`, you must already have that list somewhere then `for(j in "NUMERIC start and stop point` e.g. `for(j in 1:length(molecule)` where `length` gives the length of that list, since we want to make sure we do a loop over ever item in the list., You can then simply reference the premade list with molecule[j] which gets you the correct (jth) item in the list. 1:length() tells the for loop to start at the first item, and end at the last item.

Comment: Then, `subset` is a good way to get just the data you want. Unlist turned the subsetted data into a useable vector. as.numeric QA'd the data to make sure you are submitting only numeric data. You also tried to check logicals using versions of `algae$"VARIABLE"`, but you either have to do`algae$variable` or `algae[,"VARIABLE"]`. 

You also wasted resources by re-getting the data for max, med, and mean, whereas I did it once with `dat` and then just referenced it for each.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put together strings to make a message, use the paste function.

So instead of

```
message("The mean of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", mean)
```

Do

```
message(paste("The mean of ", j, " for ",i," is: ", mean, sep=""))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited the script, but my problem is with the for loop(s).